# Javascript val() for selectbox not linking correctly

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I'm using the niceforms plugin to style my select box. The problem I'm having is that I can't get the right javascript code to activate the links placed in the value option.

The niceforms site (http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/help/) instructs me to use the following code:

```
el.lnk._onclick = el.onclick || function () {
if(this.ref.oldClassName == "NFOnChange") {
//insert your code here
}};
```

This is my attempt at manipulating the code to allow url linking in the select drop down

```
el.lnk._onclick = el.onclick || function () {
if(this.ref.oldClassName == "NFOnChange") {    
//code i added    
window.location.href = $(this.ref).val();
}};
```

The PROBLEM is the links do not work as expected, they do not link to their corresponding values.

```
form class ="niceform"
select class ="NFOnchange"
option value = "http://link1.com" -> link1.com 
option value = "http://link2.com" -> link2.com
option value = "http://link3.com" -> link3.com
```

Please any help with this would be appreciated. I just need to insert the right bit of code to make the links correspond to their option values.

Comment: `val()` is not a JavaScript method of form elements. But jQuery provides this. Are you using jQuery? If so you should use it throughout your code.

Comment: To tell you the truth I'm not really that good at javascript and just tried any code that came close to working. Ideally the code above should have nothing to do with jquery (even though i am referencing it for other instances on my page). I tried the selectedIndex but kept getting errors akin to 'selectedIndex is undefined'.

Comment: So just as .val() won't work on a raw element, .selecctedIndex won't work on a jQuery-wrapped element.  If you have a jQuery-wrapped element, .val() is totally the way to go, but if that's not working, you need to check your assumptions (as I described below in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first off "$" is used by almost every major JS library, so:

```
window.location.href = $(this.ref).val();
```

means nothing unless you tell us which JS library you are using.

If you are using jQuery, val() should work.  I would confirm that $this.ref) is actually what you think it is by adding this right before that line:

```
console.log($(this.ref))
```

(the above assumes you use Firebug or the Chrome developer console ... if you're not using one of these tools, you should be ;-))

If that shows that you are actually selecting a SELECT element, then something funny is going on, but I suspect it isn't.

Also, as a side note I think you can probably just do:

```
$(this)
```

if you're using jQuery.

If you're not using jQuery ... tell us what you are using, and we can go from there.

Oh, and if you're not using any library, and $ is just your own custom function, then Felix was correct in pointing out that JS has no built in "value()" method on elements.  The closest you will find is .selectedIndex, which is a property of any SELECT element that tells you the index (out of all of the options) of the selected option (and then by looking at the list of available options you can tell the ".value" property of the appropriate one).

Comment: Sorry if i didn't clarify this earlier but I'm calling in the jquery framework and the niceforms plugin as well. I don't think the niceforms plugin is dependent on jquery though.

Comment: Ok, well then I think the next step is to console.log your jQuery variable ("$(this.ref)") and see if it's actually what you think it is.

Comment: (And again, to actually see the output of console.log, you need to use the Firefox plug-in Firebug, or the Chrome developer tools that are built in to Chrome, or something similar.  Alternatively you *could* use alert, but that will be painful, and if you're doing any significant amount of JS coding at all you really should get one of the above tools.)

Comment: I do have firebug (a tool i cannot live without), I placed the following code in my js file:

    el.lnk._onclick = el.onclick || function () {
    if(this.ref.oldClassName == "jumpmenu") {    
    console.log($(this.ref));
    window.location.href = $(this.ref).val();
    }};

Then i fired up firebug console and i'm not getting anything. Is there something i'm doing wrong?